# Why is my Google Sheets script function not launching directly after accepting permissions from the menu?

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, menu, spreadsheet

Google script functions do not launch directly after accepting permissions from the google sheets menu

I'm a beginner on this forum, I appologize if I don't use all good practices
I have this type of program to trigger function directly with the menu on the top of google sheet with a script example to illustrate my problem :

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('▼ MENU EXAMPLE')  
    .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('► SUBMENU EXAMPLE')
                .addItem('  - Something ', 'myFunction')).addToUi()
}
function myFunction() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveRange().setValue("value")
}
```

Everything work pretty well but I have a problem because I use this type of program with Templates, so there is copies of this document and users have to trigger the script with the menu by onopen trigger. The problem is that the first time when they click on the menu the script is launching, there is the permission menu. After agreeing the function 'myFunction' in the example will not directly trigger. They have to go back on the menu and launch again the function.
If you have already saw this problem or if you know how to bypass it i will be thankful.

Thanks you !

Comment: You have not called your function myFunction(),,, You have just declared it. Try adding `myFunction()` below the declaration.  And I would suggest making it installable and naming it something other than onOpen()

Comment: It is meant to work this way. The first time you click on the menu the user just authorizes the scopes of the script and then it won't ask you again. You need to click a second time to execute the function myFunction. On the other hand if you run directly from the script editor the function myFunction, first it will ask you permissions and then it will execute the function. You don't need to run twice the function. But you maybe don't want the user to open the scriot editor

Comment: Yeah @RamónLópezdeAndújar, thanks you for the answer. I use copy of template with on it a onOpen script to generate the menu. The problem is that the users are beginners and when they trigger the fonction from the menu they have to accept permission and they think all is good. I can't explain them to go on the script editor to trigger the fonction and also to trigger two times from the menu.